# What is asymmetric information in relation to information security?

Tags: exploit

I have just finished reading ["Why information security is hard - An economic perspective"](https://www.acsac.org/2001/papers/110.pdf), the term asymmetric information is mentioned. An example in this paper mentions

> "The technical bias in favour of attack is made even worse by
>   asymmetric information. Suppose that you head up a U.S. agency with an
>   economic intelligence mission, and a computer scientist working for
>   you has just discovered a beautiful new exploit on Windows
>   2000. If you report this to Microsoft, you will protect 250 million Americans; if you keep quiet, you will be able to conduct operations
>   against 400 million Europeans and 100 million Japanese. What’s more,
>   you will get credit for operations you conduct successfully against
>   foreigners, while the odds are that any operations that they conduct
>   successfully against U.S. targets will remain unknown to your
>   superiors."

From an economic perspective, how does this quote pertain to economics? Does this mean that the economic benefit is in the hands of the person with the information? What are other examples of asymmetric information and security?

Comment: Asymmetric information is an economic term, not an information security term, I would say you'd be better off asking this in an economics forum.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Economics.  Not sure if there is an SE for this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per requested by AEJBUG.

Asymmetric information is not strictly an economic term, but can be applied more broadly. Security and economics are two fields where the effects of asymmetric information have rather obvious and significant consequences. I will consider here only security.

Consider the perspective of attackers and defenders. A defender can never win, he can only delay the inevitable, the eventual victorious attacker. The defender have to protect against all attacks, arguably a somewhat difficult task. The attacker, however, does not, one will suffice.

This is the asymmetric relationship between the attackers and defenders.

The asymmetry stems from the fact that the attacker only have to know of one exploitable vulnerability. Even though this clearly favours the attacker the defender gains an advantage due to numbers. There are many more defenders than attackers. But I digress.

This is one of many ways to describe asymmetric information security. It probably warrants a book should one want to explain all the possible ways in which asymmetric information security reveals it self.

(By the way, I do consider Gdb's answer a good one!)

Answer (score 2):

Asymmetric information is an economic term, not an information security term. Asymmetric information is when one party in a market has more information than other parties in the same market. The theory is that asymmetric information is bad because it prevents the market from operating efficiently, and gives few parties advantage over many parties in the market. It is also in contract theory where you have 2 negotiating parties instead of a market.

In the quote above security flaws are a market, and one party has more information about that market than others. My interpretation is that the information asymmetry conveys a benefit to few while allowing all others to be exploited. The costs to the world at large from being exploited by the bug probably outweigh the benefits to the party withholding the information.

Asymmetric information happens whenever one party knows more about something than one or more other parties, and is all around us in the information security world. A few examples are:

- Cyber criminals find flaws which they exploit
- Exploited parties do not disclose breaches
- Vendors do not always share all relevant information on their products

That's just to name a few common examples, there are many more out there.

Comment: I would argue it's not strictly an economics related term but can actually be applied much more broadly, economics and security being two. In this particular situation just consider the perspective of an attacker and defender. Much more difficult to defend than to attack, asymmetric. Attacker has knowledge of a particular vulnerability which can be abused.

Comment: @Christoffer can you write this as an answer?